# DirectCast (or alternative) with a value from Array Of Type as second argument?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, types, casting

I am writing a `Class` to error report explicitly to users who sent copied & pasted data via ajax.

I am trying to properly cast `Type`s for `INSERT`ion into sql server.

The user's data is stored in an `Object(,)`.  The `Type`s are passed via `ByVal ColumnTypes() As Type` and stored inline:

```
{
    GetType(Integer), GetType(String), GetType(Integer)
}
```

for example.

How can a value from the `Array Of Type` be used as the second argument of `DirectCast` (or an alternative to `DirectCast`)?

**psuedo**

```
DirectCast(thisVariable, ColumnTypes(0))
```

for an `Integer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to achieve this.  The `DirectCast` expression can only work with named types.  Essentially values that are resolvable at compile time.  The expression `ColumnTypes(0)` is only resolvable at runtime and hence can't be used with `DirectCast` in this manner.

Instead of `DirectCast` try using `TypeConverter`

```
TypeConverter.ConvertTo(thisVariable, ColumnTypes(0))
```